# Matching k-partite graphs where all sets may only share edges with one of the sets

Tags: graphs

I'm not terribly well-versed in CS (I only just a few moments ago learned what a k-partite graph is), so forgive me if this is an obvious question.

I'm wondering how to determine if a given graph matches a specified pattern, where this pattern is an example graph that is a k-partite graph where all inter-set edges must be between one special "central" set and some other set.

I hope I'm explaining this correctly. I imagine an algorithm to take care of this (or most likely a more general case) already exists, so just a link might be the most appropriate response.

Thanks!

(P.S.: This isn't a homework problem or some made-up situation. I'm trying to do a matching of ligand-to-amino-acid graphs for a biological search tool; in my real-life case the "central" set is the ligand, the edges are bonds or interactions, and the other sets are amino acids.)

Comment: I don't understand the problem yet.  Perhaps you might edit the question to give an example problem instance?  I suggest you list an example of a graph $G$, and a pattern $P$, and tell us whether the graph $G$ matches the pattern $P$ and why/why not.  Also, it would help to define all terms and break this down into smaller, well-defined pieces.  (For instance, I don't understand what is meant by "inter-set edges", what is the central set, what is the other set, what the sets are, or under what conditions the graph is considered to match the k-partite graph that serves as the pattern.)